# Relation between DISCINT and Keep Alive interval in WebSphere MQ server?

Tags: ibm-mq, keep-alive

We had issues with lot of Applications connecting to MQ server without properly doing a disconnect. Hence we introduced DISCINT on our server connection channels with a value 1800 sec which we found ideal for our transactions. But our Keep Alive interval is pretty high with 900 sec. We would like to reduce that less than 300 as suggested by mqconfig util. But before doing that I would like to know if this is going to affect our disconnect interval value and whether it is going to override our disconnect interval value and make more frequent disconnects which will be a performance hit for us.

How does both these values work and how they are related?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP KeepAlive works below the application layer in the protocol stack, so it does not affect the disconnecting of the channel configured by the DISCINT.
However lowering the value can result in more frequent disconnects, if your network is unreliable, for example has intermittent very short (shorter then the current KeepAlive, but longer then the new) periods when packets are not flowing.

I think the main difference is, that DISCINT is for disconnecting a technically working channel, which is not used for a given period, while KeepAlive is for detecting a not working TCP connection.
And MQ provides means to detect not working connections in the application layer too, configured by the heartbeat interval.

These may help:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q015650_.htm

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.con.doc/q081900_.htm

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.con.doc/q081860_.htm

Comment: Good answer. Additionally, HBINT is the MQ channel's own heartbeat. Early MQ relied a lot on TCP heartbeats and over time the channel health monitoring has moved increasingly into the channel itself and away from TCP. The best way to keep the channels running and/or deal with orphans is to make sure QMgrs (and clients if applicable) are on later versions of MQ - preferably v7.5 or higher.